# Need help modifying my ggplot code to show error bars in my bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create boxplot with error bars, but the error bars are not displaying. Here is part of the code:

```
ggplot(data_summary, aes(x = countries, y = Mean, fill = Season)) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity", 
           width = 0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Mean - SD, ymax = Mean + SD), width = 0.2, 
                color = "black", size = 0.7, 
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  labs(x = "Countries", y = expression((O[3])(DU)), 
    title = "Bar Plot with Error Bars of Seasonal Values by Country") +
```

Comment: Please include example data such as `head(data_summary)`